# Error creating Graphviz graph using Doxygen

Tags: c, doxygen, graphviz, dependency-graph

I am trying to generate a dependency graph for my .c and .h files written by c programming using Doxygen and .dot file inside Graphviz
I have Graphviz 2.44.1 and Doxygen version 1.8.18
This error occurs and I have no idea what is wrong, I checked that the .dot file is installed correctly using the cmd command line and added it to the path variables, I also added dot path in Doxygen, Any Help?
Note: I am using Doxywizard

```
Running dot for graph 31/38
Running dot for graph 32/38
Running dot for graph 33/38
Running dot for graph 34/38
Running dot for graph 35/38
Running dot for graph 36/38
Running dot for graph 37/38
error: Problems running dot: exit code=1, command='C:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.44.1\bin\dot', arguments='"C:/Users/Eng-Nour/Desktop/DOXY TRY/latex/interrupts_8c__incl.dot" -Tpdf -o "C:/Users/Eng-Nour/Desktop/DOXY TRY/latex/interrupts_8c__incl.pdf"'
error: Problems running dot: exit code=1, command='C:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.44.1\bin\dot', arguments='"C:/Users/Eng-Nour/Desktop/DOXY TRY/latex/interrupts_8h__dep__incl.dot" -Tpdf -o "C:/Users/Eng-Nour/Desktop/DOXY TRY/latex/interrupts_8h__dep__incl.pdf"'
error: Problems running dot: exit code=1, command='C:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.44.1\bin\dot', arguments='"C:/Users/Eng-Nour/Desktop/DOXY TRY/latex/main_8c__incl.dot" -Tpdf -o "C:/Users/Eng-Nour/Desktop/DOXY TRY/latex/main_8c__incl.pdf"'
error: Problems running dot: exit code=1, command='C:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.44.1\bin\dot', arguments='"C:/Users/Eng-Nour/Desktop/DOXY TRY/latex/interrupts_8h__incl.dot" -Tpdf -o "C:/Users/Eng-Nour/Desktop/DOXY TRY/latex/interrupts_8h__incl.pdf"'
error: Problems running dot: exit code=1, command='C:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.44.1\bin\dot', arguments='"C:/Users/Eng-Nour/Desktop/DOXY TRY/latex/seven__segments_8h__dep__incl.dot" -Tpdf -o "C:/Users/Eng-Nour/Desktop/DOXY TRY/latex/seven__segments_8h__dep__incl.pdf"'
error: Problems running dot: exit code=1, command='C:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.44.1\bin\dot', arguments='"C:/Users/Eng-Nour/Desktop/DOXY TRY/latex/seven__segments_8c__incl.dot" -Tpdf -o "C:/Users/Eng-Nour/Desktop/DOXY TRY/latex/seven__segments_8c__incl.pdf"'
error: Problems running dot: exit code=1, command='C:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.44.1\bin\dot', arguments='"C:/Users/Eng-Nour/Desktop/DOXY TRY/latex/seven__segments_8h__incl.dot" -Tpdf -o "C:/Users/Eng-Nour/Desktop/DOXY TRY/latex/seven__segments_8h__incl.pdf"'
error: Problems running dot: exit code=1, command='C:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.44.1\bin\dot', arguments='"C:/Users/Eng-Nour/Desktop/DOXY TRY/latex/std__types_8h__dep__incl.dot" -Tpdf -o "C:/Users/Eng-Nour/Desktop/DOXY TRY/latex/std__types_8h__dep__incl.pdf"'
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What is the result of `doxygen -d extcmd`? Note when rerunning, **IN THIS CASE** doxygen to remove the latex directory or at least the `*.md5` files in that directory!.

Comment: Please also publish one of the dot files in the question.

Comment: Doxygen version 1.8.18

Comment: Using the doxygen wizard should not be a problem, but for debugging it is a bit troublesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**
The problem was in the Graphviz version, I used Graphviz2.38 instead of Graphviz 2.44.1 and it worked :).

Comment: Make sure you installed stable windows package .msi